# Is getAccount() enough to securing a React SPA with Azure AD B2C using MSAL

Tags: reactjs, security, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am securing a React SPA. The app is used on a private network and will only access endpoints inside the private network. I do not need to make further calls to secure a JWT so I plan to call getAccount() as the user navigates to a page along with simple time check. I cannot find the MSAL documentation for the function getAccount() but it is used in almost all of the MSAL examples. Is getAccount() a safe boolean to use to determine if the user has logged in?

Comment: I posted code I plan to use on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245300/securing-react-spa-with-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-using-msal

Comment: When adding additional information you should [edit] your question  instead of adding a comment. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming getAccount reads the id_token and not some copy of the information somewhere, then yes it should be secure enough to use since the id_token is guaranteed not to be tampered with (jwt spec)

However SPAs should never contain secure data, as they are insecure clients by definition. anyone inside the organization would likely be able to access the internal endpoints given the knowledge, if the endpoints were unsecured.
the proper way to do it would be to secure the endpoints using azure ad, expose the apis of those endpoints to the spa app registration, and have the endpoints authenticate using the tokens.

Comment: No docs on MSAL getAccount() but it seems to return null when nothing is in the session cache and it returns a tokenID, expiration date (unix timestamp), issuer, etc.. if session cache. However, the onus was on me to check the expiration date because I set up my AD B2C user flow to expire after 1 day and when I tested, getAccount() returned the old session data. So, unless the session data is immutable I cannot trust getAccount() to confirm that my app is still logged in. Also, I agree on protecting the endpoints but my concern is trusting the cached login tokenID and its validity.